# How to repair a Trac installation

Tags: linux, bug-tracking, trac, opensuse

On our Trac system, two things suddenly stopped working. The first thing is the update of the "Browse Source". The second thing is the auto-fixing feature. The only solution for the first issue is to manually run the post-commit hook of the SVN repository. But than we still have the problem, that Trac doesn't close ticket anymore depending on the SVN commit message. That was working before without any issues. Ah and a third thing is that PNG images are no longer shown in the HTML preview. The user has to download the file to see it.

Is there any known bug or issue for our described problem. Or how can I update the Trac system without loosing all the information within the Trac projects (I have set up a multi project Trac system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the following: file permissions!

To solve the issue we used the sudo in the post-commit hooks of SVN like the following:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/trac-admin /var/trac/reponame/ changeset added "reponame" $REV
```

And we had to allow the SVN user to run the trac-admin command using visudo:

```
www-data,svn        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/trac-admin
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, reboot the server :)

Can you give us some more info about your server and Trac setup?  For example, OS and version, Trac version, plugins used, etc.

It's odd for things to suddenly quit working.  If you are running a Linux system, it's possible that your server installed some updates that your system isn't fully compatible with (for example, upgrading Trac can cause some plugins to quit working properly).  Check your server's logs to see if anything was updated or reconfigured around the time Trac quit working.

Also, try setting Trac's log priority to 'DEBUG' and see if the Trac logfile contains any useful error details.

Comment: I've rebooted the server several times, but that doesn't help. My environment is the following: openSUSE 11.0 (X86-64) with Apache/2.2.8 and Trac 0.12 installed. I also activated the DEBUG logging and made a commit with a "refs" but nothing showed up in the log. Only some "DEBUG: Caching node change in [1234]" showed up.

Comment: Add an extra line to the beginning of your post-commit hook that logs a message like "Subversion hook running" to a separate file.  That way you can at least verify that the hook is indeed being run.  Also try redirecting the output of the hook script to a file so you can see if any errors are being generated.